# Touch Listener in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement touch event to change password visibility on `TextFormField`'s `suffixIcon`.

> When touched: show password; When released: hide password

But I realized using `GestureDetector`'s `onLongPressStart` will have a delay in order to call it's function.

What can I use to avoid having the delay?

Comment: Yes but you can use some sort of `Event Detector` , on tapup tapdown etc

Comment: There are many things in gesture detector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `GestureDetector` tap evets. Find the code snippets below,

```dart
class _TextFieldDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  _TextFieldDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __TextFieldDemoState createState() => __TextFieldDemoState();
}

class __TextFieldDemoState extends State<_TextFieldDemo> {
  bool _isVisible = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isVisible = false;
                  });
                },
                onTapUp: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isVisible = true;
                  });
                },
                child:
                    Icon(_isVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off)),
            title: TextField(
              obscureText: !_isVisible,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh great, so it is just my misunderstanding on the api description, I thought it required some swipe action like pull downward or push upward. Thanks, it's solved.

Comment: Ok brother. If it resolves your problem, you can approve this. It will help someone who has the same problem.